# Confusion on cycle notation

Tags: permutation-cycles

Let $\sigma \in S_4$ be the permutation that sends $(a,b,c,d) \to (b,d,a,c).$
Then the cycle notation is $(1342)=(23)(34)(12).$

But if we denote $a$ as $1,$  $b$ as $2$, $c$ as $3$ and $d$ as $4,$ then it means $\sigma(1)=2, \sigma(2)=4, \sigma(3)= 1$ and $\sigma(4)=3.$ Hence, isnt the cycle notation $(1243)$ instead?

Kindly advise, thank you.

Comment: You have found the two different interpretations of cycle notation. Some authors use one, some use the other. As long as whoever is writing makes it clear at the start how to interpret cycles, there's no harm done.

Comment: By the way, the way I learned to do cycle multiplication, $(23)(34)(12)=(1243)$.